# How to send MSMessage in Messages Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, msmessage

I want to implement an imessage app, however being new to the messages framework and iMessage apps being such a new thing there aren't many resources. So I am following the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/224/) and using Apples providing [sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/IceCreamBuilder/Introduction/Intro.html) for a guide.

I have three views, the `MessageViewController` which handles pretty much all the functionality and then a `CreateViewController` and a `DetailsViewController`.

I am simply trying to create an `MSMessage` from the `CreateViewController` and display in the `DetailsViewController`.. then add to the data.

However I get a crash when trying to create the data.

```
@IBAction func createAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //present full screen for create list
    self.delegate?.createViewControllerDidSelectAdd(self as! CreateViewControllerDelegate)        
}
```

The data type I am trying to pass is the dictionary from a struct:

```
struct data {
var title: String!
var date: Date!

var dictionary = ["title" : String(), "Array1" : [String](), "Array2" : [String]() ] as [String : Any]

}
```

So here's how things are set up;

**MessagesViewController**

```
class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController, {

// MARK: Responsible for create list button

func composeMessage(for data: dataItem) {

    let messageCaption = NSLocalizedString("Let's make", comment: "")

    let dictionary = data.dictionary

    func queryItems(dictionary: [String:String]) -> [URLQueryItem] {
        return dictionary.map {
            URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1)
        }
    }

    var components = URLComponents()
    components.queryItems = queryItems(dictionary: dictionary as! [String : String])

    let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
    layout.image = UIImage(named: "messages-layout-1.png")!
    layout.caption = messageCaption

    let message = MSMessage()
    message.url = components.url!
    message.layout = layout
    message.accessibilityLabel = messageCaption

    guard let conversation = activeConversation else  { fatalError("Expected Convo") }

    conversation.insert(message) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}

}


extension MessagesViewController: CreateViewControllerDelegate {

func createViewControllerDidSelectAdd(_ controller: CreateViewControllerDelegate) {
    //CreatesNewDataItem
    composeMessage(for: dataItem())
}

}
```

**CreateViewController**

```
/**
 A delegate protocol for the `CreateViewController` class.
*/
protocol CreateViewControllerDelegate : class {
func createViewControllerDidSelectAdd(_ controller: CreateViewControllerDelegate)

}

class CreateViewController: UIViewController {

static let storyboardIdentifier = "CreateViewController"

weak var delegate: CreateViewControllerDelegate?

@IBAction func create(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //present full screen for create list

    self.delegate?.createViewControllerDidSelectAdd(self as! CreateListViewControllerDelegate)

}

}
```

Would someone show where I am going wrong and how I can send a `MSMessage`? If I am able to send the message I should then be able to receive and resend.

Comment: What might be the problem is passing the struct `dataItem` in the function `func composeMessage(for data: dataItem)` I have managed to send a string value without using a struct like in this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe-J7OsQHhI

Comment: @RileyDev   - That youtube video helped!

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see, without being able to debug this myself:
you are setting your components.queryItems to your dictionary var cast as [String:String], but the dictionary returned from data.dictionary is not a [String:String], but a [String:Any]

In particular, dictionary["Array1"] is an array of Strings, not a single string. Same for dictionary["Array2"].  URLQueryItem expects to be given two strings in its init(), but you're trying to put a string and an array of strings in (though I'm not sure that you're actually getting to that line in your queryItems(dictionary:) method.

Of course, your dataItem.dictionary is returning a dictionary with 4 empty values.  I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: I have actually commented out QueryItems function and the dictionary, jus set the message manually but still get a runtime crash

Comment: whats the text in the console when it crashes?  What line does it stop at?

Comment: Is the code in your question up to date with your project?  I don't see a createList() method on CreateViewController

Comment: Sorry, your line:     self.delegate?.createViewControllerDidSelectAdd(self as! CreateListViewControllerDelegate)
 should probably read     self.delegate?.createViewControllerDidSelectAdd(self as! CreateListViewController) since CreateListViewController is not its own delegate

Comment: and actually, you don't need the cast at all, just self.delegate?.createViewControllerDidSelectAdd(self)

Comment: Sorry `MessagesExtension`CreateViewController.create(AnyObject) -> ():` and that is exactly what I was trying but get the error `Value of type `CreateViewControllerDelegate` does not conform to expected type CreateViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: send me the project via UPWORK and I'll try to sort it out.

Comment: I've submitted a proposal as Jay Wardell.  I don't think I can message you until you message me.